# 正規表現で1〜15行目とそれ以降の行をグループ化したい

Tags: ruby, 正規表現

## やりたいこと

```
1行目
2行目
3行目
4行目
5行目
6行目
7行目
8行目
9行目
10行目
11行目
12行目
13行目
14行目
15行目
16行目
17行目
```

にという文章に対して
1〜15行目にfirst
latterに16行目以降でグループ化したい

## やったこと

`/(?<first>\A(.*\n){15})(?<latter>.*\z)/`
1回目のmatchのせいか、`.*\z`で文字列の末尾までマッチしない
rubular: http://rubular.com/r/AQbZAuF7Xs

解決できる正規表現がありましたら教えてください。
環境はruby: 2.5.1です
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: `/^(?<first>(.*?\n){15})(?<latter>.*)/m` も有効かと。

Answer (score 1):

`.`は改行を含みません。`.*\n`も改行を含まないことを前提に記述されているはずです。

```
/(?<first>\A(.*\n){15})(?<latter>(.*\n)*\z)/
```

とかどうでしょうか？